# AWS Amplify + Cognito: Create account without username/Use email instead of username?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm new to AWS and had a question about adding a user through the Amplify portal. I have the settings for email or phone number, but when I try and create a user, it requires a username.

I would rather have a user input an email in the place of a username, but not exactly sure of the dynamics of AWS Amplify.

**AWS Cognito Settings:**

[image]

**AWS Cognito Create User (Online Portal):**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Cognito, it will always have a `Username` field that is considered separate from the rest of the attributes. It also contains a `phone_number` and `email` attribute which are considered separate from the username. So if you want a user to sign up via email and/or phone number, then you will submit an email/phone number as the username, AND you'll also submit the email and/or phone number in their respective fields if you want to use them for verification or account recovery options.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Although, realise AWS doesn't let you change a username in Cognito.  So using the email/phone number there is not the best idea.

Comment: What if you want to use a uuid for the username?